# Building a Maven project into another Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, package

I am creating a Maven project with a package (Proj A) that I would like to import into another project (Proj B), so that Proj B can import that package and use its classes and methods. I have tried editing the pom.xml file of Proj B to include Proj A as a dependency, I have tried building a path on Proj B to have Proj A, I have also tried to include the jar file produced after mvn install/clean package as a library for Proj B to use, and still, the import of the package is not recognized on Proj B. I am new to Maven, so help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Showing some maven code and possibly your folder structure would be helpful.

Comment: I cannot really show anything because it's confidential info. But I can go into the generics and describe the setup if that's helpful?

Comment: maybe what your are looking for is a multi-module maven project. Here is the documentation: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: So to give more context, I am creating a master Maven project with a package containing classes and every possible method I would require. I would then like to find a way to import that package into other projects so that I can just create objects of classes in that package and use whatever method I want.

Comment: You're doing the right thing by adding Proj A as a dependency in Proj B. You have to make sure that you at least perform an install on Proj A so that its jar file will be available in your local maven repository, otherwise Proj B won't be able to load it. You may need to perform a refresh in your IDE so that the maven plugin picks up the new jar.

Comment: So, when I install Proj A, I get a WARNING: JAR will be empty.  And I see that after I add Proj A as a dependency for Proj B, the project itself is listed under the Maven dependencies but [without test code]. Would this be an issue? However, I do see the jar file for Proj A in my .m2 file.

Comment: If you get a warning that the jar will be empty, then you have probably not put the source code into the correct directory (`src/main/java`).

Comment: Update: @JF Meier, I fixed up the location of the source code, and things worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Make sure your source code is in the right directory.